# Domain extension required localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: azure, office365, skype-for-business

I am trying to verify domain ( http://localhost/ ) for Single sign on [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) for skype for business online.

I am getting below error :

[image: Error]

Kindly help me to identify what I am doing wrong. If nothing is wrong then, what's the domain extension for **localhost** (.com for google.com, .net and etc).

**Edit** :
  I am trying to provide App URL ID for a application registered in Azure AD. To do this, first of all, I have to verify domain by adding it for single sign on. During adding I am getting error message as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add the localhost domain to Azure AD. It has to be an actual domain name purchased from a domain registrar.

One reason is that `localhost` has a different meaning for every person, it means their computer.

What are you trying to achieve?

EDIT: Your app ID URI identifies your app. It does not need to be a URL that points to your app but has to be a verified domain. For the App ID URI you can put a value such as `https://mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/MyAppName`. This is a typical scheme I use. Just replace "mycompany" with your Azure AD directory name. `mycompany.onmicrosoft.com` is a default domain you get with the directory, so you can use that. Also replace "MyAppName" with your app's name.

The App ID URI just needs to be in a domain that is in the AAD, which that one is by default. It does not need to be the URL for your app, it is just an identifier.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I have updated question. Whats the purpose of APP URL ID. What value I should provide when working in local.

Comment: See my edit, it is just an identifier, you can use the default AAD domain in that.